# Multiprocessing not working for same function

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a heavy process I want to use Multiprocessing for and execute simultaneously. However, when I run it using multiprocessing -- the processes are spawned but they are not using any system resources to execute. I looked up a multiprocessing example shown on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiprocessing-python-set-1/)

Expected Results : Running Multiprocessing on the dataset using `multiprocess_dataset()` function given below

Code:

```
import Extractor
import DatasetReader

import gc
import pandas as pd

def batched_extraction(sub_data_df, file_batch_name, COL_NAME):
    
    print('File {} started processing!'.format(file_batch_name))
    
    result = [Extractor(row[COL_NAME]).get_all_phrases() for idx, row in sub_data_df.iterrows()]
    sub_data_df['result'] = result
    
    sub_data_df.to_csv('Outputs/file_batch_name', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    
    del phrases, sub_data_df
    gc.collect()
        
def multiprocess_dataset(formatted_df):
    
    batched_num_reviews = len(formatted_df)//4
    
    print('Multicore process 4 batches of {} reviews each'.format(batched_num_reviews))
    
    sub_df_1, sub_df_2 = formatted_df[:batched_num_reviews], formatted_df[batched_num_reviews:2*(batched_num_reviews)]
    sub_df_3, sub_df_4 = formatted_df[2*(batched_num_reviews):3*(batched_num_reviews)], formatted_df[3*(batched_num_reviews):]
    
    file_batch_name_1 = 'output_multiprocess_input_file_b1_{}_reviews.csv'.format(len(sub_df_1))
    file_batch_name_2 = 'output_multiprocess_input_file_b2_{}_reviews.csv'.format(len(sub_df_2))
    file_batch_name_3 = 'output_multiprocess_input_file_b3_{}_reviews.csv'.format(len(sub_df_3))
    file_batch_name_4 = 'output_multiprocess_input_file_b4_{}_reviews.csv'.format(len(sub_df_4))
    
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name="process1", target=batched_extraction, args = (sub_df_1, file_batch_name_1, COL_NAME))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name="process2", target=batched_extraction, args = (sub_df_2, file_batch_name_2, COL_NAME))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(name="process3", target=batched_extraction, args = (sub_df_3, file_batch_name_3, COL_NAME))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(name="process4", target=batched_extraction, args = (sub_df_4, file_batch_name_4, COL_NAME))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

def main():
    
    INPUT_FILENAME = input('Enter input filename : ')
    COL_NAME = input('Enter column on which you want to process on : ')

    df = DatasetReader('Datasets/{}'.format(INPUT_FILENAME)).read_dataset()
    df[COL_NAME].replace(np.nan, "EMPTY")
    
#    num_reviews = len(df)
#    print('Running process for {} reviews'.format(num_reviews))

    multiprocess_dataset(formatted_df = df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Actual Result / Stack Trace at running the program:

```
(phrase) viole@viole-X510UNR:~/Documents$ python3.6 program.py
/home/viole/Documents/phrase/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/service/predictors/__init__.py:23: FutureWarning: allennlp.service.predictors.* has been depreciated. Please use allennlp.predictors.*
  "Please use allennlp.predictors.*", FutureWarning)
/home/viole/Documents/phrase/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:434: UserWarning: Setting attributes on ParameterList is not supported.
  warnings.warn("Setting attributes on ParameterList is not supported.")
Enter input filename : accomm_dataset.csv
Enter column on which you want to process on : comments
Multicore process 4 batches of 6386 reviews each
File output_multiprocess_input_file_b1_6386_reviews.csv started processing!
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 10205.12it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]File output_multiprocess_input_file_b2_6386_reviews.csv started processing!
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 10255.02it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]File output_multiprocess_input_file_b3_6386_reviews.csv started processing!
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 60.89it/s]
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 25115.59it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 3446.43it/s]
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 13706.88it/s]
File output_multiprocess_input_file_b4_6386_reviews.csv started processing!
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 59.78it/s]
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 26546.23it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 3440.77it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Your label namespace was 'pos'. We recommend you use a namespace ending with 'labels' or 'tags', so we don't add UNK and PAD tokens by default to your vocabulary.  See documentation for `non_padded_namespaces` parameter in Vocabulary.
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Your label namespace was 'pos'. We recommend you use a namespace ending with 'labels' or 'tags', so we don't add UNK and PAD tokens by default to your vocabulary.  See documentation for `non_padded_namespaces` parameter in Vocabulary.
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 171.89it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 44.97it/s]
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 27962.03it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 2983.15it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 60.82it/s]
<---Expanding Contraction--->
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 19508.39it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 2906.66it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Your label namespace was 'pos'. We recommend you use a namespace ending with 'labels' or 'tags', so we don't add UNK and PAD tokens by default to your vocabulary.  See documentation for `non_padded_namespaces` parameter in Vocabulary.
Your label namespace was 'pos'. We recommend you use a namespace ending with 'labels' or 'tags', so we don't add UNK and PAD tokens by default to your vocabulary.  See documentation for `non_padded_namespaces` parameter in Vocabulary.
```

I checked my System Monitor to see resources being used -- all cores are lying idle. I tried running `Extractor` without multiprocessing and it seemed to work alright. Is there anything I am missing here?

Any help would be appreciated!